# How to alert a user their browser is not the latest version?

Tags: javascript, html

I found a .NET version of this, but can't find a javascript/jquery way to do this. I test my site in the latest IE/Chrome/FF/Safari/Opera.  That is a difficult enough task (to me) without adding backward compatibility.  The message will be to simply use another browser which is up to date.  Are there any scripts that do this?  I'm hoping to find a resource that tracks this sort of thing so I don't have to.

Comment: You could use http://www.browser-update.org/, but... do you really think people will upgrade their browsers just so they can look at your site?

Comment: @ WanderNauta I do not care what they think.  This answer is not at all in line with my post.  I did not ask for a way to tell users to upgrade.  I will inform them that the functionality will not work unless they are using the latest version of a browser.  It is up to them to make a decision: update, use another browser, or nothing.  If they do nothing, that is their loss.

Comment: Usually you don't have to do anything to achieve this. Many browsers check for updates automatically and either tell the user when there's an update ready or they update themselves automatically. For example Chrome updates on every start and checks for updates even more regularly.

Comment: @user1006177: If people are doing nothing, they are *not* visiting your site, which is usually your loss.

Comment: Why do you expect your pages to work on the latest versions only? Are you sure that when a new version is published, your page will stop working on the version that was newest before that (and that it will work on the new version)?

Answer (score 1):

You could navigator.appVersion to find the versions and filter the relevant version using navigator.appName which can give you a version number you can compare against a minimum required version that you could set.

Using somthing like this [(JSFiddel)](http://jsfiddle.net/uzCgB/) you could break down the string and get the version.

```
var objappVersion = navigator.appVersion;
var objAgent = navigator.userAgent;
var objbrowserName = navigator.appName;
var objfullVersion = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
var objBrMajorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
var objOffsetName, objOffsetVersion, ix;
if ((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("Chrome")) != -1) {
    objbrowserName = "Chrome";
    objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 7);
}
else if ((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("MSIE")) != -1) {
    objbrowserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
    objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 5);
} // In Firefox
else if ((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("Firefox")) != -1) {
    objbrowserName = "Firefox";
}
else if ((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("Safari")) != -1) {
    objbrowserName = "Safari";
    objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 7);
    if ((objOffsetVersion = objAgent.indexOf("Version")) != -1) objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 8);
} // For other browser "name/version" is at the end of userAgent
else if ((objOffsetName = objAgent.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1) < (objOffsetVersion = objAgent.lastIndexOf('/'))) {
    objbrowserName = objAgent.substring(objOffsetName, objOffsetVersion);
    objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion + 1);
    if (objbrowserName.toLowerCase() == objbrowserName.toUpperCase()) {
        objbrowserName = navigator.appName;
    }
}
if ((ix = objfullVersion.indexOf(";")) != -1) objfullVersion = objfullVersion.substring(0, ix);
if ((ix = objfullVersion.indexOf(" ")) != -1) objfullVersion = objfullVersion.substring(0, ix);
objBrMajorVersion = parseInt('' + objfullVersion, 10);
if (isNaN(objBrMajorVersion)) {
    objfullVersion = '' + parseFloat(navigator.appVersion);
    objBrMajorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion, 10);
}
```

Example code from [here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-detect-different-browsers-and-their-versions-using-javascript/25424).

However it would probably be more beneficial to check for compatibility using the individual features that may lack support and inform the user of any incompatibility's and explain any ramifications.

Answer (score 0):

Check what these guys did: [Browser Update Initiative](http://browser-update.org/update.html). You can integrate it easily and they offer code samples: http://browser-update.org/

It is going to be much harder to implement on your own and you will have to regularly update your browser version data.

Comment: It does *not* check for latest version. It checks for versions older than some version defined in the code.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You are wrong to some degree. Every implementation is going to do just that. Browsers don't have a version API and thus you need to check against hardcoded versions. So what you need is to regularly update those versions and follow browser development. That is what these guys do for you. They have all that implemented and running and they provide a simple API to access that date + a script that adds a notification if you are running on an outdated browser.

Comment: The question was “How to alert a user their browser is not the latest version?” I was simply pointing out that the sofware recommended does not do that.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela On the contrary. It does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have a warning message in a div, and this div is hidden in a subsequent media query section. Only browsers supporting CSS 3 media queries will then auto hide this warning message div.

Comment: But that's just a feature detection of media queries?